# Idiomatic approach to conditional update of key

Tags: redis

I'd like to use Redis to cache the most recent piece of data that a user has sent to me. However, I can't just use `SET`, because the user may send data out of order, I need to condition the `SET` based on the value of another key, e.g.:

```
latest_timestamp = GET "latest_timestamp:<new_data.user_id>"
if latest_timestamp < new_data.timestamp {
  SET "latest_timestamp:<new_data.user_id>" new_data.timestamp
  SET "latest_data:<new_data.user_id>" new_data.to_string()
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A server-side Lua script (see [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval)) is the idiomatic-est approach IMO.

Make sure that your code passes the full names (i.e. does all substitutions) of both keys, as well as the new timestamp and the new data as arguments. The script should look something like this:

```
local lts = tonumber(redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]))
local nts = tonumber(ARGV[1])
if lts < nts then
  redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], nts)
  redis.call('SET, KEYS[2], ARGV[2])
end
```

Comment: Itamar, thanks for the reply, I agree but I would outline how using an hash with two fields for time/value leads to zero concerns regarding using Redis Cluster or other partitioning schemas.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @antirez - I indeed considered adding this note myself, and then discarded it in the favor of focusing on the matter in hand. As Lua is somewhat of tough nut to crack for some, I preferred to keep this specific optimization for some other discussion :)

Comment: Could @antirez or someone elaborate on why using a "hash with two fields for time/value" might be better than a simple timestamp?